# Circular reference is user defined function VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, circular-reference

My aim is to add the values of certain columns using a user defined function in the actual row. The columns are given in another table. I am reading the name of rows, calculating the actual value and sum them. This function called once from excel but executed 4 times. At the end it indicates a circular reference error. There is no such error in the excel file, I checked if the udf return just 42 then there is no error. First I suspected Application.Caller, but ruled out.

```
Function SumColumnsWithSuffix(suffix As String, rowNumber) As Integer
    'can be used only in Összesíto table
    Dim myTable As Excel.ListObject
    Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim myRow As Excel.ListRow

    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("összesíto")
    Set myTable = mySheet.ListObjects("Számlák")
    Dim columnName As String

    result = 0

    For Each myRow In myTable.ListRows
        columnName = Intersect(myRow.Range, myTable.ListColumns("Oszlop név").Range)
        columnName = "Összesíto[" & columnName & " " & suffix & "]"
        'actualRow = Application.Caller.row
        'rowName = actualRow & ":" & actualRow
         rowName = rowNumber & ":" & rowNumber
         myRowRange = Range(rowName)
         actualValue = Intersect(Range(columnName), Range(rowName))
         result = result + actualValue
     Next myRow

    SumColumnsWithSuffix = result
End Function
```

Comment: I would declare more variables and not reuse them for different types of data.  It will make your code clearer and may help you uncover simple errors.  Put `option explicit` at the top of you VBA file to enforce some of these behaviors.  You use `columnName` to hold both a range reference (from `Intersect`) and then to hold a range address (a string).  This may be creating a string you do not expect.

Answer (score 1):

`myRowRange` is not explicitly declared (or used, actually) so it is implicitly a `Variant`.  That means your assignment here...

```
myRowRange = Range(rowName)
```

...is also making an implicit call to `.Value`.  That call will evaluate the results of every single cell in `Range(rowName)` to populate the array of `Variant` that it returns.  If *any* of those cells contains a call to `SumColumnsWithSuffix`, you'll get a circular reference.